# WP8 High Fill Rate due to several updates to UI Elements?

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that contains three grids on the MainPage (all 480*800). These grids are content-packed (average of 20 textblocks), and are updated with weather data. When the app starts, the API is called and updates each textblock and UI Element.

There are swiping gestures (up & down) to navigate between this grids, and a corresponding animation. However, I noticed that in the latest build, the animations stutter and the fill rate jumps from about 2.02 to 3.79.

I've been doing some testing with the app over the past few ideas, and I found that if nothing gets updated, the animations are buttery smooth and the fill rate stays near 1.5. I also tested Data Binding - no change.

Is there any way to avoid this issue? Or could it be something else? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: XAML: http://pastebin.com/Ltb82WmG

Comment: Code: http://pastebin.com/wJ4Hartj